# How to change specific element on ajax ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have ajax call that change the user info. And I want to get the value from the response and change value of specific element

Example: the element that need to chage:

```
<div id="changeMe"><!-- New Value --> </div>
```

Ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "?rr=profile",
}).success(function(response) {

});
```

How to change the value of the "changeMe" element **ONLY** ?

Comment: $('#changeMe').html(response) in your success

Comment: really need an answer? google may have helped you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with

```
$.ajax({
    url: "?rr=profile",
}).success(function(response) {
var r = $( response ).find( "#changeMe" );
    $( "#changeMe" ).html( r.html() );  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "?rr=profile",
}).success(function(response) {
   $('#changeMe').html('Your new content');
});
```

This will change the element with the ID "changeMe".  See also [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

To get a value you can use the same method.
Example:

```
var res = $('#someOtherElement').html();
```

The variable res has now the content of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following line.

```
$('#changeMe').html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.html()` or `.text()` jQuery methods depending on your requirements (whether the response content is HTML or plain text):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "?rr=profile",
}).success(function(response) {
  $('#changeMe').html(response);
});
```

switch `.html(response)` with `.text(response)` if that's better for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your success function your can do like below

```
.success(function(response) {
   $("#changeMe").append("Your value");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text then :

```
$('#changeMe').text('new data from response');
```

If you want to change CSS as well :

```
$('#changeMe').css('property', 'attribute');
```